# Wrong password when connecting to facebook via curl

Tags: php, facebook, curl

And so I'm trying to connect to facebook with my php script. However facebook returns a wrong password error and I'm sure I've written good password. My code:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init(); 
$url = "https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1";
$post = 'email='.urlencode('**@**.**').'&password='.urlencode('****');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://www.facebook.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
echo $txt = curl_exec ($ch);
?>
```

Comment: I would assume the person that gave you written permission to scrape Facebook can help you: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol, I was sure input name was password, I was wrong - input name was pass :D.